# WordPress. Custom shortcode name convert to a link

Tags: wordpress

I had such a task. It is necessary that the name of the shortcode be converted into a link. 
Example steps:
1.Edit area ---> *This is example text with [tag id="Shortcode-Custom-Title"]* 
2.php magic connect this shortcode to link *"example.com/product-tag/"* like this ---> *example.com/product-tag/**shortcode-custom-title*** 
3.Site front shown up result without dashes in title ---> *This is example text with [Shortcode Custom Title](http://example.com/product-tag/custom-shortcode-title)*

I know i can create many shortcodes with my custom text and return link rule, but maybe it is possible do automatic. 
Thank You for any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress shortcodes can be added to the functions.php which should reside in your themes folder.

An example of how to implement your example above would be:

```
function custom_link_func( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'productid' => 'my-product-id'
        ), $atts );

    return '<a href="http://example.com/product-tag/' . $atts['productid'] . '">' . preg_replace("/-/", " ", $atts['productid']) . '</a>';  //Replace dashes "-" with spaces " ".
}

add_shortcode( 'custom_link', 'custom_link_func' );
```

You can create the link in your Wordpress pages like this:

[custom_link productid='Shortcode-Custom-Title']

which will return: [Shortcode Custom Title](http://example.com/product-tag/Shortcode-Custom-Title)

**EDIT: For more on how to access shortcode attributes please see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts**

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately, this is not what I need. Your example returns the text of a non-clickable link. Also, the problem of dashes is not solved. In my example, step number 3 describes the result that I need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Adam, I think I understand your goal better now.  Try the above edits which will produce the anchor tag and strip dashes from the title $atts passed to the shortcode.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm. After paste your code, for some reason site stop working. :(

Comment: Adam,I think I placed one too many arguments in shortcode_atts.  Try the above now.  Also you may want to check your logs for any errors produced and place them here.

Comment: No any errors in log file, but still after paste your code, site is down.